# Saddle Point by the Cauchy-Riemann Equations

Tags: complex-analysis, self-learning

Consider the following complex integral

$$
\int_{\mathcal P} e^{v\cdot w(z)} \xi(z) dz,
$$

where $v$ is large and positive and the integration path $\mathcal P$ satisfies the following two conditions:

1. $\mathcal P$ passes through a zero $z_0=x_0+iy_0$ of the derivative $w'(z_0)$ of $w$;
2. the imaginary part of $w$, $\Im w(z)$ is constant.

If we write

$$
z = x+iy, \; w(z)=u(x, y)+iv(x,y); z_0=x_0+iy_0; w'(z_0)=0.
$$

Then it is claimed that by the Cauchy-Riemann equations:

$$
u_x = v_y, \; u_y=-v_x.
$$

It follows that $(x_0, y_0)$ cannot be a maximum or a minimum but must be a saddle point on the surface $S: (x,y)\mapsto u(x,y)$. Why is this so, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to find whether something is a saddle point, you need to look at the second derivative of the function. There is a test you can use that has 4 possible cases.

$$ 1. \; u_{xx} < 0 \quad u_{xx} u_{yy}- u^2_{xy} > 0 $$
$$ 2. \; u_{xx} > 0 \quad  u_{xx} u_{yy} - u^2_{xy} > 0 $$
$$ 3. \; u_{xx} u_{yy} - u^2_{xy} < 0 $$
$$ 4. \; u_{xx} u_{yy} - u^2_{xy} = 0 $$

In case 1 $z_0$ is a max, in case 2 it's a min, in case 3 it's a saddle point, and in case 4 we can't determine what type of maximum it is. Because $z_0$ is analytic we can then use the Cauchy-Riemann conditions to relate $u_{xx}$ and $u_{yy}$ and find 
$$ u_{xx}+u_{yy} = 0.$$
This proves that $u_{xx} u_{yy}- u^2_{xy} $ is always negative and therefore cases 1 and 2 are impossible if the Cauchy-Riemann conditions are satisfied. The reasoning goes like this. Since $u_{xx}$ and $u_{yy}$ have different signs, their product will always be less than or equal to zero. It's also obvious that $-u^2_{xy}$ is less than or equal to zero. Therefore, the whole term must be less than or equal to zero.

Comment: How to get $u_{xx} u_{yy}- u^2_{xy}<0$? BTW, in the third and forth cases, shouldn't it be $u_{xx} u_{yy}- u^2_{xy}$, please?

Comment: Ah yes I've had a typo.